# How to set variable equal to JsonProperty attributes of nested classes...C#

Tags: c#

I have some nested classes with fields and each has a JsonProperty attribute assigned:

```
 public class LacerteFixedAssetRoot
{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public FixedAssetResults Result;
}
public class FixedAssetResults
{
    [JsonProperty("fixedAssets")]
    public List<LacerteFixedAsset> FixedAssets;
 }

public class LacerteFixedAsset
{
    [JsonProperty("bookMethod")]
    public BookMethod BookMethod;
}
public class BookMethod
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type;
}
```

What I want to do is read the JsonProperty of each field in each class and assign a variable to the value of the JsonProperty. Case and point:

```
var result = await ApiCall();
var companies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LacerteFixedAssetRoot>(result);
var jsonPropName = companies.Result.FixedAssets.First().BookMethod.Type;
```

yes, the above code will give me the value in 'companies.Result.FixedAssets.First().BookMethod.Type' but i want the JsonProperty attribute of each field. How do I read the JsonProperty of my classes?

If someone shows me one, I can probably get the rest.

Thanks

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Like my classes. Thats where I got the JsonProperty names from

Comment: take a look at the following fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/VfuMSN

Comment: @ademg this definitely points me in the right direction. Post it as the answer so I can give you proper credit.